# How can I replace emails with usernames?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

At localhost I want to replace all of emails with their usernames. This is not works:

```
UPDATE `users` SET 'email'='username'
```

What is the working code?

Comment: When addressing fields, you need to remove the quotes (or use backticks: ```)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a field called `username` in the data:

```
update users set email = username;
```

Your code is confusing back quotes with regular quotes (which are used only to delimit strings).  You could also write:

```
update `users` set `email` = `username`;
```

Back quotes are used to enclose column and table names, particularly when they have unusual characters (like spaces) or conflict with reserved names.

Answer (score 0):

because you have wrap the column name with single quotes. Remove it and it will work.

```
UPDATE users SET email = 'username'
```

backticks are only used to escape reserved keywords or column names and tables names that have special characters on it. More explanation on the link below.

- [MySQL - when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

but if you mean to copy the values of column `username` into `email`, you need to remove the quotes on both column,

```
UPDATE users SET email = username
```